# How to use x-frame option in angular 5

Tags: angular, iframe

I am New to angular I want to set x frame option so that I can use iframe .Data coming dynamically from different url like facebook video or youtube. I found url [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) but how to implement in angular.`<iframe width="420" height="315" [src]="name.sourceLink" frameborder="0"></iframe>`
can any one guide or suggest me way to implement in angular.

Comment: The X-Frame-Options is something you specify server side, not on angular side

Comment: I thought there is solution at client side thank you.. :)